# Socket.IO Java Client to Jar

Tags: java, android, jar, socket.io

I'm trying to compile Socket.IO Java client to JAR file but have no luck. I need it for Android project to comunicate with Node.JS Socket.IO.

The Socket.IO Java client is this one: https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client

I do it like its said in github wiki, but no luck:

```
cd $PATH_TO_SOCKETIO_JAVA
ant jar
ls jar/socketio.jar
```

I tryed it with:
Java Sun 6, Java Sun 7 and Java Open 6 (JDK, JRE)

I noticed, that the `build.xml` file does not contain all of the paths as they should be. For example path to eclipse directory. So what should I do. Maybe I can build the jar somehow else?

Comment: The build.xml in github doesn't have the target 'jar' anymore or any task that builds jar. Look at the history of build.xml, some of the older files have 'jar' task. May be you can copy that task and include it in the latest version.

Comment: @sperumal dear sir. I would gladly accept your answer if you would write it as one and maybe more detailed so community could refer to it, since I know few others could be searching the same answer.

Comment: @JānisGruzis Thanks I added my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of this writing, the build.xml in github doesn't have the target *jar* anymore or any task that builds jar. Latest version of auto generated build.xml seems to have dropped the *jar* task. Look at the history of build.xml, some of the older files have *jar* task. May be you can copy that task and include it in the latest version.

**@HeatfanJohn**: This is the code that I added to `build.xml` to allow `ant jar` to successfully build `socketio.jar`

```
    <target name="jar" depends="build-project">
            <mkdir dir="jar"/>
            <jar destfile="jar/socketio.jar" basedir="bin">
                <zipgroupfileset dir="libs/" includes="*.jar"/>
                <manifest>
                </manifest>
            </jar>
    </target>
```

Comment: This problem is logged as [issue #12](https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client/issues/12) in GitHub.